# Dynamically display multiple copies of an imported component

Tags: svelte

How to display multiple copies of the same component dynamically in Svelte?

**An example:**

In my App.svelte I have a container div called Sky.

I display a Moon component which is imported from a separate file and invoked the traditional way:

```
import Moon from "./Moon.svelte"
... 
<Moon></Moon>
```

Now I want to add stars the same way, by importing a Star component and displaying it at random positions. I added a button "Add stars" and calculated random numbers, but I have no idea how to invoke the component and add it to the Sky container div:

```
<button on:click={()=> {
    randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*200);
    randomY = Math.floor(Math.random()*200);
    let sky = document.getElementById("thisSky");
    //Add star to DOM at random left and top position... 
    }}>
    Add Stars
</button>
```

**Solution:**

I added this function:

```
export function addStar() {
   new Star({
    target:     document.querySelector('#sky')
            })
    }
```

It searches the parent component and set it as the target of the Star component.

see sky.svlete in:

https://svelte.dev/repl/6c81da4202644303b435327ecbabf82e?version=3.43.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your answer works, this is generally speaking a bad pattern to follow.  In Svelte you should try to have your DOM be represented of some kind of 'state' and avoid any direct DOM manipulation like you are doing here.

The `Svelte-way` to do this is to have an array of stars and push an new star to that array, then use an `each` block to render all the stars:

```html
<script>
 import Star from './Star.svelte';
 let stars = []
 export function addStar() {
   stars = [...stars, {}];
 }
</script>

<div>
  {#each stars as star}
    <Star {...star} />
  {/each}
  <slot />
</div>
```

This way you can also expand further and have `addStar` actually receive the position of the star and pass it on to the component itself.

It also allows you to remove or replace stars, something that is not possible with your solution.